# How to display dot using Custom Numeric Format Strings in C#

Tags: c#, tostring

I want to display `decimal` product price in format `100 грн.` (Ukrainian hryvnia). When I use currency pattern `.ToString("c")` I get `₴` sign, I don't want to use it, so I decided to try something like `.ToString("#.## грн.")` but the dot isn't displayed. I get `грн` output but expect `грн.`. How can I accomplish that? I want to use string pattern as the part of the localization so I could use something like `.ToString(Settings.CurrencyOutputPattern)` where `CurrencyOutputPattern` is `"c"` for `USD`, `"#.## грн."` for `UAH`and `"#.## руб."` for `RUB`

Comment: are you familiar with the string.Format() function @DmytroTsiniavskyi

Comment: try this: `.ToString("#.##") + " rph."`

Comment: @MethodMan, @DrKoch I want to use string pattern as the part of the localization so I could use something like `.ToString(Settings.CurrencyOutputPattern)` where `CurrencyOutputPattern` is `"c"` for `USD`, `"#.## грн."` for `UAH`and `"#.## руб."` for `RUB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a literal `.` by enclosing it in single quotes:

```
.ToString("#.## грн'.'")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your own extension of String/Decimal to make it to grivan

```
public string ToGrivna(this decimal ammount)
{
    return ammount.ToString("0.##")+" грн."
}
```

Comment: I need to use output pattern as one string

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: if you are not sure @COLDTOLD  what the OP means then perhaps you should remove your answer since it does not meet nor answer the needs of the OP

Comment: Posting an answer may help other people searching for 'How to display dot using Custom Numeric Format Strings' that may not follow the patern needed by OP.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to change the currency, then you can clone the `CurrentCulture` and modify it.

```
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "грн.";

decimal num = 10.24M;
string str = num.ToString("c", culture);
```

If you want to control where the currency is written (left o right), there are two properties of `NumberFormat`: [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) and [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern(v=vs.110).aspx)

For example here in Italy we use € 10.00

Comment: In this case I will have to implement some `public string ToCurreny(this decimal price)` method and replace existed code which I already have (in a pretty big solution) `.ToString(CurrencyOutputPattern)` where `CurrencyOutputPattern` is localized string. I'm just looking for some easy and fast way just to change pattern value.